# asp .net mvc ajax submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem that's driving my crazy for sometime. I have an asp .net mvc page(.ascx). This view has a form which can be ajax submitted to a controller action. I have an ajax submit button that posts the form.

In the view I have some if conditions as follows

```
 If(Model.SampleID.HasValue) 
{
  
    alert('sample created');
    alert('');
  
}
```

This code works fine when I hit the ajax submit button, I mean the javascript gets executed. But when I hit the enter key, the same post happens but the javascript code is not executed at all. I don't know why this happens.

Any thoughts or comments?

Comment: Maybe you could post the html containing your form and little more of your jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. Could be that your ajax submit button is only binded to the click event. If so u will have to bind it to the keypress event.Yes its better that you post the html.

Answer (score 0):

put the following code in in the document.ready() function

```
$("input").keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which==13)
    {
        //Your Submit Method
    }
});
```

Comment: This is bad practice.  What if they tab to the button and press the space bar?  This will fail and doesn't handle all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to differ from the others who have posted and say that you are binding your jQuery wrong to your form submission and you need to rework that.  **Do not** bind to mouse click on the button and **do not** inspect keydowns.

Instead, forms have a [**`submit`**](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event that can be bound to.  It won't matter whether they click the submit button, press enter, or tab to the button and press the space bar.  Bind thusly:

```
$('#yourformcontainer form').submit(function() {
     //Your custom submit code here
     //return false if you want to abort the form submission, true (or nothing) otherwise
});
```

This makes the assumption that your HTML form is rendered something like this:

```
<div id="yourformcontainer">
    <form>
        ...
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```